# Python classproperty with inheritance

Tags: python, class, subclass

Bit of a funky situation here. Is it possible to set up a "classproperty" with inheritance in python?

I have the following situation. I have a base class with a lot of functionality. I have overwritten the constructor with a classmethod "instantiate_from_somewhere_else". Now this constructor has to use a value, thats set on the class. I am currently achieving this via another classmethod my_prop.
However, I find this rather ugly and would much prefer if I could access the my_prop without having to call the method (i.e. use cls.my_prop or self.my_prop instead of cls.my_prop() and self.my_prop())

```
class base(object):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        ... do things

    @classmethod
    def my_prop(cls):
        return 'base'

    def func_to_use_property(self):
        print(self.my_prop())

    @classmethod
    def instantiate_from_somewhere_else(cls,**kwargs):
        res = call_external(cls.my_prop(),**kwargs)
        return cls(res)


class sub(base):
    @classmethod
    def my_prop(cls)
        return 'child'
```

Seems like I had a bit of a brainlag here. This seems to do the trick:

```
class Base(object):
    my_prop = 'base'

    def instantiate_from_somewhere_else(self):
        return self.__class__.my_prop

class Derived(Base):
    my_prop = 'derived'
```

Comment: `my_prop = 'child'` and `my_prop = 'base'`?

Comment: Regular class attributes seem to do the job just fine. Why have a classmethod or classproperty at all?